# Cannot access on-premise Web API through Azure Hybrid connection

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-hybrid-connections

I deployed a web API at port 8090 on an on-prem server. Created a hybrid connection to on-prem server using port 8090. Status is connected. I deployed an Angular application as a Web App to Azure but AJAX request fails with "Name not resolved".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the fully qualified name of the server your application is hosted on, e.g. http://server.contoso.com/myservice rather than http://server/myservice as you would do locally.